# Why do clearcase static views not update checked out files?

Tags: clearcase

I have a static view with some files checked out that I am working on. Someone else checks in a bunch of changes that I want to add to my view. So, I run update on my view. It turns out they changed a file I have checked out. Now my view is left only partially updated and may not even compile until I figure out which checked out file I have to manually merge.

I know I can reserve my checkouts, but that blocks other devs from checking in stuff they are done with.

According to: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm

> update does not apply to files or directories that are checked out to the current view.

So, it seems it's working as the atria/rational/IBM folk want it to work. I don't understand why it works this way.

Is there any way to update my static view and also automatically merge changes into my checked out files?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to update my static view and also automatically merge changes into my checked out files?

Not really, since a checked out file is a file being modified locally, and `cleartool update` tries very hard to not touch any local file.

Your checked out file is selected by the `element * CHECKEDOUT` selection rule, which means any update won't update it (it is already selecting the right version).

You need to check in those file (triggering the merge, similar to "[To merge the latest version to a hijacked file](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/t_merge_latest_ver_hijack.htm)"), and check them out again.

But that isn't always possible since it would make a work in progress visible (checked in) to other views in the same branch.

The only other solution is to compute a patch between the checked in version and your checked out file, and apply that patch `cleartool lsco -all -s -cview | xargs cleartool diff -diff`, with the difficulty to diff between your checked out version and the LATEST version.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I don't understand how that command is supposed to work. I get the lsco to find the checked out files, but I don't get the diff command to do the merge. I think the xargs command will put one file on the end of the diff command? Diff needs 2 file names to diff right? I'm working in windows, so no xargs, but I can do "for /f %i in ('cleartool lsco -all -s -cview') do @cleartool diff -diff %i". That diff command spits out "cleartool: Error: At least two objects must be supplied to compare." Is there a command to do the same thing that gets done at check in?

Comment: @DanielKnueven "I don't get the diff command to do the merge": it isn't there to do a merge, it is there to compute a patch that you will have to apply. And the difficulty would be to find the right versions (CHECKEDOUT vs. LATEST) in order to diff them. Regarding xargs, you have all Unix commands available on Windows (without needing Cygwin) with Gnu On Windows: https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki